# A strange problem with Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: nvidia, suspend, 15.10, nouveau, kde5

I have been using Fedora for ages, but the new laptop that I purchased came with Ubuntu installed and I decided to give it a try. I regretted it almost immediately but continued out of sheer stubbornness. But recently it finally went overboard.

I have been using 15.10 since its release. I have an nvidia card on my laptop, and had to switch between proprietary drivers and nouveau because after some upgrades either one or another ceases to work properly (for example, stops recognizing an outside monitor or causes problems after suspend to RAM). Before the latest upgrade I had nouveau working reasonably well although sometimes the laptop would refuse to suspend to RAM.

First, plasmashell got into the habit of crashing during the resume. Since I do not reboot my laptop very often (that might make me redo some rather lengthy computations) I had to restart it by hands.

Now after I enter my password at the login screen, The screen goes black. It stays like that for some time and then I get back the login screen. I can switch to the console but restarting sddm or X server manually does not help. Neither does removing all config files in my home directory. The only thing that helps is rebooting the system in recovery mode and then resuming the normal boot (there is no need to do anything else after booting in the recovery mode). I would settle for this as a temporary solution but after a suspend to RAM the system does not power up the screen at all (even the consoles do not work).

Replacing nouveau by nvidia does not help either; I tried several versions available in the repositories, but the outcome is always the same. With nvidia even the boot in the recovery mode does not help.

Comment: Several versions?  What type of card do you have?

Comment: GK107GLM (Quadro K1100M). I tried nvidia-361, nvidia-358 and nvidia-355.

Comment: Wow, none of those are in the official repository.

Answer (score 0):

The only download for this card available from the nvidia website is the "linux long lived driver" version 352.

I suggest you try installing version 352 from the actual official Ubuntu repositories, especially if you have problems after every update.

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

Please post any errors or further issues.

Comment: It did not help (the only difference is that with nvidia rebooting in recovery mode does not change anything), but it seems that I have the potential culprit now: libqxcb.so (from the package libqt5gui5). At least, this library is mentioned in several crash messages I see in dmesg after KDE crashes on startup.

Comment: I found bug reports with exactly the same issue. The workaround is to remove .local/share/kscreen directory

Comment: @Green136 okay, so did you try this or not (did you install the correct driver, nvidia-352)?

Comment: yes, I tried 352 and it did not resolve this issue. The culprit turned out to be a recent bug in qt5 which I was able to bypass by removing everything in .local/config/kscreen. Now my system is usable (with nouveau), so I will stick to it for the time being.